# R: what is the size of the vector or what is the structure of the vector when initializing it with NULL

Tags: r

The following code can work, but how to understand such initialization.

Thanks.

```
a_vector <- NULL

n = 100 # or a whatever number you give

for(i in c(1:n)){
    a_vector[i]=i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to understand object size of you are talking about length, but here goes my understanding.

You can use `lobstr` package to measure their sizes, base R has a function called `object.size` as well. Let us try to measure the object size in following way.

```
library(lobstr)
x <- NULL
obj_size(x) ## 0 B with type NULL with length 0

for(i in 1:1000){
   x[i] <- i
}
```

`obj_size(1L) ## object of size of any number is here 56 B`,
Check with large number it would still return 56 bytes

But, obj_size(x) after iteration would return here is 4048 bytes, if you check the `typeof(x)`, its an integer, So how come if a single object is taking 56 bytes, but 1000 of them only returns 4048 bytes?, If we check closely, we see that first `obj_size(x[1:2])` returns 56 bytes only, however if you do `obj_size(x[1:3])` you will get 64 bytes if you keep doing this , you will realise `obj_size(x[1:8])` returns only 80 bytes. You can check these object size within the loop like  I did below (created y) and track how the object size are changing. You can see at the end of loop both object x and y have similar sizes provided they have similar data types, I have to coerce y to integer as obj_size returns a double value.

```
x <- NULL ## 0 bytes initialization used only as NULL
y <- vector('integer', 1000) ## 4048 bytes, initialized before loop the value will remain same after the loop ends
for(i in 1:1000){
  
  x[i] <- i
  y[i] <- obj_size(x[1:i])
}
y <- as.integer(y)

obj_size(x) ## 4048 bytes with length of x as 1000
objd_size(y) ## 4048 bytes with length of y as 1000
```